# Embedding pictures into a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sending out the Cat  signal. I need to get what's on the screenshot. The images were obtained from [IMBD](https://www.imdb.com/):

[image]

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,
                positioning}
\tikzset{
    mymatrix/.style = {matrix of math nodes,
                      nodes in empty cells,
                      nodes={minimum height=3ex, minimum width=1em,
                             inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center,
                             draw, very thin,scale=0.9,transform shape},
                      column sep=0pt,
                      row sep=0pt,
                      inner sep=0.5\pgflinewidth, outer sep=1pt,
                      draw, thick},
 empty node/.style = {draw,fill=none},
every label/.append style = {font=\large, text=teal}
    }
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@empty@cell{%
\iftikz@lib@matrix@empty%
\node[name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,empty node]{};\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
\matrix (m1) [mymatrix,
              label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left: },
              label=below:$R$,
              label=above:,
              nodes={fill=white}]
{
1   &   & 3 &   &   & 5 &   &   & 5 &   & 4 &   \\
    &   & 5 & 4 &   &   & 4 &   &   & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
2   & 4 &   & 1 & 2 &   & 3 &   & 4 & 3 & 5 &   \\
    & 2 & 4 &   & 5 &   &   & 4 &   &   & 2 &   \\
    &   & 4 & 3 & 4 & 2 &   &   &   &   & 2 & 5 \\
1   &   & 3 &   & 3 &   &   & 2 &   &   & 4 &   \\
};
\node (approx) [right=of m1] {$\approx$};
\matrix (m2) [mymatrix=none, right=0.1em of approx,
              label={[rotate=90, anchor=south east,xshift=-0.7em]left: },
              label=below:$Q$,
              label=above:,
              nodes={minimum width=2.4em}]
{
    0.1& -0.4  & -0.2 \\
    -0.5& 0.6 & 0.5 \\
    -0.2& 0.3 &0.5  \\
    1.1& 2.1 & 0.3 \\
    -0.7&2.1  & -2 \\
    -1& 0.7 & 0.3 \\
};
\node (times) [right=of m2] {$\times$};
\matrix (m3) [mymatrix=none, right=of times,
              label={[rotate=90, anchor=north]right: },
              label=below:$P^T$,
              label=above:]
{
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It all depends on how you want to align the pictures relative to the text.  `\raisebox{-0.5\heoght}{\includegraphics[width=1em]{...}}` should do the trick, or at least if you weren't rotating everything 90 degrees.

Comment: Actually my MWE could be thrown off and we could do a new simple matrix from scratch. We’re not sticked to the MWE whatsoever, If it makes things hard, we can remove it.

Comment: It must be me. I don't understand this question either.

Comment: @cfr I need to get those 3 matrices as they appear on the screenshot along with the space for adding the images. I put a mwe just to save some time. I don’t know how to do the task i’m asking for.

Comment: But your matrices are different sizes from those at the top i.e. for `n x m` `n` and `m` are different?

Comment: Yes, that does not matter at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have your graphics, nor do I follow external links. So you need to replace the lists of `example-image-duck`s by your own file names. Other than that it is mainly the same as the post you are using.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,shapes.arrows}
\tikzset{marrow/.style={minimum height=1.4cm,minimum width=1.2cm,
   single arrow, single arrow
    head extend=.125cm, single arrow head indent=.08cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mymat/.style={matrix of nodes,column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,row sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,
 nodes in empty cells,cells={nodes={draw,text depth=0.2ex,text height=1.75em,minimum
 width=1.9em,minimum height=1.9em,execute at begin node=\vphantom{1}}}},
 node font=\sffamily,>=stealth]
 % first matrix
 \matrix[mymat,column 1/.style={nodes={font=\Large}}] 
 (mat1) {
  |[text=blue]|\faUser & 5 & 3 & & & 3 \\
  |[text=green!70!black]|\faUser & & & 4 & &  \\
  |[text=purple]|\faUser & 4 & |[fill=blue!20,text=red]| ? & & 3 & 5  \\
  |[text=red]|\faUser & & & & &  \\
  |[text=orange]|\faUser & & & & &  \\
  |[text=black]|\faUser & & & & &  \\
 };
 % pics above first matrix (replace them by your own)
 \foreach \Pic [count=\Y starting from 2] in 
  {example-image-duck,example-image-duck,example-image-duck,example-image-duck,example-image-duck}
 {\node[above=0.1ex of mat1-1-\Y]{\includegraphics[width=1.8em]{\Pic}};} 
 % arrow
 \node[right=1ex of mat1,marrow,draw](marr){};
 % second matrix
 \matrix[mymat,right=1ex of marr,row 3/.style={
 nodes={/utils/exec={\unless\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=1
 \tikzset{fill=blue!20}
 \fi}}},
 column 1/.style={nodes={font=\Large,draw=none}}] 
 (mat2) {
  |[text=blue]|\faUser &  &  &\\
  |[text=green!70!black]|\faUser & & &   \\
  |[text=purple]|\faUser & & &  \\
  |[text=red]|\faUser & & &   \\
  |[text=orange]|\faUser & & &   \\
  |[text=black]|\faUser & & &   \\
 };
 %
 \draw[cyan,<->] ([yshift=1ex]mat2.north-|mat2-1-2.west)  -- 
 ([yshift=1ex]mat2.north-|mat2-1-4.east) node[midway,above,black]{$k$};
 % third matrix
 \matrix[mymat,right=2.5em of mat2.north east,
 column 2/.style={nodes={fill=blue!20}}] 
 (mat3) {
  & & & & \\
  & & & & \\
  & & & & \\
 };
 %
 \draw[cyan,<->] ([xshift=-1ex]mat3.west|-mat3-3-1.south)  -- 
 ([xshift=-1ex]mat3.west|-mat3-1-1.north) node[midway,left,black]{$k$};
 % pics above third matrix (replace them by your own)
 \foreach \Pic [count=\Y] in 
  {example-image-duck,example-image-duck,example-image-duck,example-image-duck,example-image-duck}
 {\node[above=0.1ex of mat3-1-\Y]{\includegraphics[width=1.8em]{\Pic}};}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much. You're a piece of work, that I can tell you